# Use batch generated preview images for template_icon_view

Tags: python, scripting, objects, image

I want to build some sort of library(like Pro Lighting for excample) for the products of a customer. Since the products only have product numbers, I would like to include the batch generated preview images. 
Is there a possibility to access those images via Python? Particularly with template_icon_view?

Comment: Hmm, it probably could be accessed using python. I'll take a look.